# Dart's pub get command can't find latest versions of some dependencies

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I've noticed on a few occasions that when I setup some dependencies in my pubspec.yaml pointing to the latest version, they aren't found when I run `pub get`.

For instance, the dependency [source_gen](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/source_gen). The latest version of source_gen is clearly `0.5.0+1`. So I'll setup my pubspec.yaml file as follows:

```
dependencies:
  source_gen: "^0.5.0+1"
```

Then I run `pub get`, and I get the following error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Package source_gen has no versions that match >=0.5.0+1 <0.6.0 derived from:
- ServerErrors depends on version ^0.5.0+1
```

I tried several of the most recent versions, without much luck. Finally if I do the following:

```
dependencies:
  source_gen: any
```

and then run `pub get`, source_gen version 0.4.7 is installed. I'm not sure I understand why. I'm using the dart sdk version 1.16.0. This is the second dependency I've had this issue with and I'm a little confused.

**EDIT:** As requested by Gunter, the full list of my dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  http: "^0.11.3+7"
  dartson: "^0.2.5"
  intl: "^0.12.7+1"
  mailer: "^1.0.0"
```

Comment: Can you please post all `dependencies` and `dev_dependencies` your `pubspec.yaml` file contains?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Edited the question and added a full list of dependencies at the bottom.

Comment: Weird. It worked for me, but I'm using 1.17.0-edge. Removing dependencies and check if it changes anything is usually a good approach to figure out which dependencies are causing the issue. Then usually manual investigation of the `pubspec.yaml` files of these depenencies (for example looking up the source in their GitHub repo) is necessary. Quite cumbersome but resolving dependencies is a complex problem. I guess the Dart team will improve this eventually but it's a quite difficult problem and currently they have more pressing topics.

Comment: This is the second time you've answered my dart related question I believe, so you seem to have a pretty good grasp of the language. What are the more pressing topics that need to be handled by the dart team?

Comment: I hope that non-null types will be introduced in Dart2. They are working on generic methods which are supported quite well already (with comment syntax). Besides that I like it how it is. Better integration with native code would be great (server-side only, for example for better Database support). I guess most other issues are work in progress anyway and will be made available in the not so far future (like better integration with JS projects but that doesn't concern me directly) There are always tons of things that could be better but in overall its a great language and great tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known issue of `pub`. This means `pub` just wasn't able to resolve a compatible set of dependencies. Unfortunately the error message is misleading.
`pub` also prints the same error when one of the dependencies isn't compatible with the used Dart SDK version.

Comment: I see. `dartson` ended up being the issue. Removing that dependency allowed me to link the latest `source_gen`